# Response does not contain zero integers

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey, jackson

I have restful API and use Jetty as a server. I send a post request to create my object which contains some `skill` list. Skill contains of `String` *id* and `Integer` *value* fields. When I use `0` or `"0"` for my Integer field with the get response I get the skill array without *value* field at all.

```
@XmlRootElement
@JsonAutoDetect(isGetterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE,
        creatorVisibility = Visibility.NONE, fieldVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class Skill
{

    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty(value="id")
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private java.lang.String _id;

    @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty(value="value")
    @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull
    private java.lang.Integer _value;

    // getters and setters
}
```

My request body is like this:

```
{
  // some other fields
  "skills": [{
    "id":"Swedish",
    "value":0
  },{
    "id":"Finnish",
    "value":"0"
  }]
}
```

After applying necessary changes to my object I pass it to be returned via this line:

```
Response.ok().entity(myObject).build();
```

The body of the get response is like this:

```
{
  // some other fields
  "skills" : [ {
    "id" : "Finnish"
  }, {
    "id" : "Swedish"
  } ]
}
```

With other values everything works fine, however, 0 seems to be so special that it doesn't even include this field to the object.

***The question is Why and How can I solve it?***

Comment: Are you using jersey with Jackson or Jax-rs as the JSON provider?

Comment: Have you tried using private int _value; instead? int is not nullable. If you convert an object to json with Integer as null it will hide the field

Comment: Mby try to remove NotNull validation and change Integer to int.

Comment: Agree, the problem is that this Skill is generated object (generated by YaaS) which is transformed from json to object and it seems impossible to have primitive type there unfortunately.

Comment: @dambros, I am not 100% understand your question, but in general my service is based on this template: https://devportal.yaas.io/gettingstarted/createaservice/index.html#2

Comment: @dambros, so, I mixed up something. The point is that I use Jetty as a server, but the implementation of Response.ok().entity(myObject).build(); is from Jersey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The problem is in version of Jackson library.*

When we add `JsonFeature` by default we have `serializeJsonEmptyValues=false`.

In this case in the method `JsonFeature#initDefaultObjectMapper` we will come to the point where we do `objMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY);`

If we have a look to the javaDoc of `NON_EMPTY` field, we will see the following:

> Compatibility note: Jackson 2.6 included a wider range of "empty"
>   values than either earlier (up to 2.5) or later (2.7 and beyond)
>   types; specifically: Default values of primitive types (like 0 for
>   int/java.lang.Integer and false for bool/Boolean) Timestamp 0 for
>   date/time types With 2.7, definition has been tightened back to only
>   containing types explained above (null, absent, empty String, empty
>   containers), and now extended definition may be specified using
>   NON_DEFAULT.

So, which means that if you use the version 2.6 the zeros will disappear. And this happens to be in our project because we use Redisson which uses the version 2.6. of Jackson library.

Comment: I'm using 2.8.5 and need to have `MAPPER.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);` to include the zeros in the response. (note the NON_EMPTY will remove the zeros)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in Jetty, Jersey or YaaS. The problem seems to be in Jackson. Jackson does the serialization/deserialization and seems to have some optimization, thus `zeros` are skipped.

Unfortunately I haven't found any resource yet which says exactly why would you skip 0 and I didn't manage to find the place in Jackson code where this happens.

**Possible solutions:**

1. Use annotation `@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.ALWAYS)` for your field and it will not be skipped.
2. Don't allow zeros for your `Integer` field.
3. Use `String` type instead of `Integer`.

The problem is that my object is generated by YaaS, thus, I cannot just change by generated object and not sure if YaaS has the possibility to generate the object with the annotation from the 1 item. I assume that in this case the 2 option might be the best.

Answer (score 0):

you have different value types for similar keys:
int 0 for "value" of "Swedish" and String "0" for "value" of "Finnish".
This may cause problem if some kind of object by fields building is involved.

Comment: It seems that jersey doesn't care about that and transform it at some point, maybe because it is json object and everything is string there. Anyway, with other values, for example, 2, everything works fine, however, 0 seems to be very special.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I didn't use @javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.

What I had was

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);

MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
myClass.setStringField("some value");
myClass.setIntField(0);

String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);

System.out.println(json);    // --> { "stringField" : "some value" }
```

It didn't print the intField with value zero. All I had to change was the NON_EMPTY rule to this:

```
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_ABSENT);
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myClass);
System.out.println(json);    // --> { "stringField" : "some value" }
```